# How to retrieve the display name that represents a specified Account Rights constant?

Tags: c++, winapi, msdn

I am trying to work out which Win32 API function is appropriate for retrieving the display name of an **Account Rights** (User Rights) constant name.

I am aware the `LookupPrivilegeDisplayName` function exists to retrieve the display name that represents a specified Privilege, but not the Account Rights.

For example, the `SeDenyInteractiveLogonRight` constant (Account Rights) is mapped to the display name `Deny log on locally`, which you can see in the *Local Group Policy editor* (`gpedit`) in Windows.

See information on Account Rights Constants, which I am trying to fetch the display names for these 10 constants.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/windows/desktop/SecAuthZ/account-rights-constants

I have searched in MSDN and Googled without success. Anyone who knows the appropriate function that can do the job please tell me. Thanks.

Comment: not exist piblic api for this. function [GetRightDisplayName](https://i.imgur.com/C0kIx5W.png) do this. the actual strings was inside files like *Windows\System32\en-US\wsecedit.dll.mui* (language dependent)

Comment: There is no function to do this conversion. The group policy editor has its own custom lookup table to convert one to the other.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to `GetRightDisplayName`. Yes there is no documentation in MSDN. I am wondering if there is a hidden header file that might be used to invoke this hidden function?

Comment: @Trevor - the *GetRightDisplayName* is **not exported** function inside *wsecedit.dll*. because it not exported you can not get it address (if not use *wsecedit.pdb* which need first download in general case). can not get address - can not call. the `GetRightDisplayName` first try use *LookupPrivilegeDisplayName* and if it fail - do several *_wcsicmp* calls for compare *lpName* with some hard-coded names - *"SeNetworkLogonRight", "SeInteractiveLogonRight", etc..* and if match found - load display name with *LoadString* call (really it loaded from alternative resourse dll)